# XML Exception when compare with a number in SELECT with CASE statement

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

I used `CASE` statement in `SELECT` function as following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a < 0 THEN 0
            ESLE a
            END AS "Number 1"
FROM <TABLE_NAME>
```

This function is in an XML file of a C# website.

When I open that site, it's display an `XMLException`:

> The '0' character, hexadecimal value 0x30, cannot begin with a name.
>   Line ..., position ...

I had searched out and fix as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN XMLExists('[a < 0]') THEN 0
            ESLE a
       END AS "Number 1"
FROM <TABLE_NAME>
```

but still got the Exception.
How could I fix this? Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XML file *literally* contains `WHEN a < 0` then I'm not surprised you're getting an exception - that's not valid XML. It's got nothing to do with the SQL side of things as your attempted fix suggest. You should be escaping the `<` as `&lt;`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a &lt; 0 THEN 0
```

In an XML file, that's how you represent *text* of `SELECT CASE WHEN a < 0 THEN 0`.

Better yet, *don't hand-edit the XML at all*. If the file had been created with an XML API, it would have done this escaping for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. This saved my day.